# Rebus: Sun Archaic Ancient Antique

Tags: rebus

I have yet another Rebus puzzle for you all to solve.....

This time I've tried making it neither too hard nor too easy :P

Here it is

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That one is:

> "Old stuff + Old stuff + Old stuff under SUN" = **"There is nothing new under the sun"**

Comment: Seriously? Five minutes???? That's all?? You've gotta be kidding me!

Comment: And when you posted this answer, you made it wrong, since the answer was new...

Comment: hahahaha Nice one!! @KSmarts